# How to get the letter coordinate retrieved by Tesseract ocr

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to handle tesseract in python to just do simple job:
 - open a picture
 - run ocr
 - get the string
 - get the characters coordinates

The last one is my pain!

Here is my first code:

```
import tesseract
import glob
import cv2

api = tesseract.TessBaseAPI()
api.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZéèô%")
api.SetPageSegMode(tesseract.PSM_AUTO)

imagepath = "C:\\Project\\Bob\\"
imagePathList = glob.glob(imagepath + "*.jpg")

for image in imagePathList:
    mBuffer=open(imagePathList[10],"rb").read()
    result = tesseract.ProcessPagesBuffer(mBuffer,len(mBuffer),api)
    img = cv2.imread(image)
    cv2.putText(img,result,(20,20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.0,(0,255,0))       
    cv2.imshow("Original",img)
    cv2.waitKey()
```

As my picture get various layouts, with different words at different positions, I would like to get a box for every char.

I have seen talking about:
 - api.getBoxText
 - Hocr

But no way has been found to implement it in Python.

Answer (score 3):

[tesserocr](https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr) provides the capability to access pretty much all of tesseract's API functionality. Here's an [example](https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr#getcomponentimages-example) that might be what you want:

```
from PIL import Image
from tesserocr import PyTessBaseAPI, RIL

image = Image.open('/usr/src/tesseract/testing/phototest.tif')
with PyTessBaseAPI() as api:
    api.SetImage(image)
    boxes = api.GetComponentImages(RIL.TEXTLINE, True)
    print 'Found {} textline image components.'.format(len(boxes))
    for i, (im, box, _, _) in enumerate(boxes):
        # im is a PIL image object
        # box is a dict with x, y, w and h keys
        api.SetRectangle(box['x'], box['y'], box['w'], box['h'])
        ocrResult = api.GetUTF8Text()
        conf = api.MeanTextConf()
        print (u"Box[{0}]: x={x}, y={y}, w={w}, h={h}, "
               "confidence: {1}, text: {2}").format(i, conf, ocrResult, **box)
```

You can also access other API methods such as `GetHOCRText` and `GetBoxText` among others.

However, right now it only supports *nix systems although a user [successfully compiled it on Windows](https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr/issues/19#issuecomment-267742262) and provided binaries if you'd like to give it a try.

Disclaimer: tesserocr author here.

Comment: @iMath it's a usage example. You can use `RIL.WORD` to iterate words instead, there's also `RIL.SYMBOL` to iterate letters...

Comment: Your tips does work, but it seems that if you restrict the recognition area with `api.SetRectangle(box['x'], box['y'], box['w'], box['h'])`
, the text recognition correction rate is lower than  the free restricted way ,i.e. `self.tessBaseAPI.SetImage(image);print('-----all text------',self.tessBaseAPI.GetUTF8Text())`, so what's under the hood ?

Comment: You're better off asking a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to call `GetHOCRText` method instead, if it's supported by the Python wrapper.